# VS 2015 Community Edition Update 2 Not Installing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, installation-package

I already had Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 3 installed on my computer but realized some programs won't run with it and I needed to downgrade to Update 2. I found this [link](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=1998) which is the version I need but whenever I run the setup it retrieves Update 3 in the list. I can't seem to get Update 2 installed. Is it because I had the Update 3 installed before? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Maybe someone knows a direct link to the Update 2 ISO!

Thanks.

Comment: why do you think a downgrade would fix the issue? You run into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). ask your original issue and not an issue you get with your wrong approach to fix your original issue.

Comment: I have the same code compiling on 2 computers side by side, one on VS 2015 CE Update 2 (which works perfectly) and another on VS 2015 CE Update 3 (which compiles but doesn't work). Upon researching, I saw many others have had similar issues. So, I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with my approach and I know for a fact that downgrading will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to completely remove the VS 2015 community with update 3? If not, please try to download the [VisualStudioUninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) to clean up and delete Preview, RC and final releases of Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015, as well as early previews of Visual Studio 2017, and you can run it for several times.

Follow this document: [How to: Install a Specific Release of Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653628.aspx) to download the VS community 2015 RTM version from the same website that you shared in [here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015%20community) , then use the specific command like *vs_community.exe /OverrideFeedURI http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/B/06BB0C5C-C767-4250-91DA-AB463377597E/20160405.3/enu/feed.xml* or *vs_ community.exe /OverrideFeedURI http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/6/B/06BB0C5C-C767-4250-91DA-AB463377597E/20160405.3/enu/feed.xml* to install the VS community 2015 with update 2 per your requirement.